# Creating A Weekly Schedule - No Dates, Just Week Days and Times

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm attempting to build a weekly schedule for a campus radio station using Ruby on Rails and/or Javascript, and trying to figure out an approach to generate either (A) a table with days as columns and time slots as table cells with rowspans to accommodate variable shows of variable duration, or (B) responsive columns for each day with divs of variable height for each show.

Currently I have database tables for time slots (start time, end time), shows, and week days (eg Monday).

I need to account as well for the fact that there may be empty slots, or that when admin is adjusting time slots for shows.

All existing information (ice cube gem, jquery full calendar, google results, stack overflow results, etc) that I have been able to find deals with events that have dates. In my case, date is irrelevant, it's just a weekly show that happens eg every Friday 1-2pm.

So for example I could have a fixed set of time windows in a database table eg monday 9-9:30; monday 9:30-10 and then allow each window could belong to a particular time slot, so

```
time_window: {starts: 9, ends 9:30, time_slot_id: 1}
time_window: {starts: 9:30, ends 10:00, time_slot_id: 1}
time_slots: {show_id: 1} and a time slot has_many :time_windows
```

or else creating something similar to full calendar where shows get overlayed in the appropriate spots based on their day and start/end times.

I realize it's a somewhat vague question. I'm wondering if anyone has dealt with a similar problem, and what research, techniques or technologies, or design patterns they may have found useful in the process.